# Boltzman exploration with more than two actions in Q-learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am using Boltzman exploration in Q-learning where I have at least 10 actions in each state. I know that with only two actions, Boltzman exploration can be applied quite simply as follows:

1. Calculate pr1 and pr2 for the two actions with the Boltzman exploration equation.
2. Generate a random number *r*
3. Assuming pr1>pr2. If r<=pr1, take action corresponding to probability pr1. If r>pr1, take action corresponding to pr2.

However, how can I do this with 10 actions? At each decision step, I update the probabilities of all the actions. This gives me a probability distribution of all the actions where the probability of best action is highest. How do I select action in this case using the Boltzman exploration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excellent discussion of weighted random sampling: [Darts, Dice, and Coins](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/).

And here is my implementation of the Vose's Alias method:

```n
class WeightedRandom
{
    private alias : array[int];
    private prob  : array[double];

    private random : Random;

    public this(p : array[double], random : Random)
    {
        this.random = random;

        def n = p.Length;

        alias = array(n);
        prob  = array(n);

        def small = Queue(n);
        def large = Queue(n);

        def p = p.Map(_ * n : double);

        foreach (x in p with i)
            (if (x < 1.0) small else large).Enqueue(i);

        while (!small.IsEmpty && !large.IsEmpty)
        {
            def s = small.Dequeue();
            def l = large.Dequeue();
            prob[s]  = p[s];
            alias[s] = l;
            p[l] = p[l] + p[s] - 1;
            (if (p[l] < 1.0) small else large).Enqueue(l);
        }

        while (!large.IsEmpty)
            prob[large.Dequeue()] = 1.0;

        while (!small.IsEmpty)
            prob[small.Dequeue()] = 1.0;
    }

    public NextIndex() : int
    {
        def i = random.Next(prob.Length);
        if (random.NextDouble() < prob[i])
            i;
        else
            alias[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have negative rewards in Q-matrix. I use the Boltzman formula in the same way to calculate the probabilities and to pick the greedy action (minimum value with minus sign) with the maximum probability. The problem is that when the value of _T_ (temperature coefficient) becomes too small, I get infinite values as probabilities. To avoid this, I used the technique as described in http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/dissertations/2011-0120-200243/hasselt.pdf (page 53).

Comment: But perhaps this technique is suitable for positive rewards. Because I get wrong (maximum) probabilities in some state-action pairs. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

There is perhaps nicer ways to do it but the main idea is this:

```
def weighted_choice(weights):
    r = uniform(0, sum(weights))
    for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
        r -= weight
        if(r < 0):
            return i
```

where weights is the list of pr1,pr2,.. and the returning value is the index of the winning action